# Criação inicial de dados no banco com .HasData() não cria

Tags: c#, .net

Tenho essa classe de contexto, e a ideia é criar as roles e um usuário admin de início. As roles são cridas, porém os usuários não. O banco é criado em outro momento, aplicando as migrations pendentes. Não dá nenhum erro, já debuguei, ele passa direto mas os usuários não são criados no banco, alguém tem ideia do por quê?

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<CustomUser, IdentityRole<int>, int>
{
    public DbSet<CustomerInfo> CustomerInfos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> opt) : base(opt)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUser>()
        .HasOne(u => u.CustomerInfo)
        .WithOne(c => c.User)
        .HasForeignKey<CustomerInfo>(c => c.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
            .HasOne(ci => ci.CustomerInfo)
            .WithOne(a => a.Address)
            .HasForeignKey<CustomerInfo>(a => a.AddressId);

        CustomUser admin = new()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Usuario",
            UserName = "usuario.admin",
            Email = "usuario.admin@hotmail.com",
            NormalizedUserName = "USUARIO.ADMIN",
            NormalizedEmail = "USUARIO.ADMIN@HOTMAIL.COM",
            Status = true,
            CreatedOn = DateTime.Now
        };

        PasswordHasher<CustomUser> passwordHasher = new();
        admin.PasswordHash = passwordHasher.HashPassword(admin, "Pas$word!2");

        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUser>().HasData(admin);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole<int>>().HasData(new IdentityRole<int>
        {
            Id = 99999,
            Name = "admin",
            NormalizedName = "ADMIN"
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole<int>>().HasData(new IdentityRole<int>
        {
            Id = 88888,
            Name = "user",
            NormalizedName = "USER"
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<int>>().HasData(new IdentityUserRole<int>
        {
            RoleId = 99999,
            UserId = 1
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Já descobri oq era. Achei que essa parte acontecia em tempo de execução, mas preciso gerar a migration antes. As roles eu já tinha, tentei adicionar os usuários depois.